# Is every subset of a RE language also RE, in general?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, chomsky-hierarchy

I'm trying to understand the question in my title in an intuitive way: 
If I have an RE language A, then some TM, say TM(A) accepts on it. If I take a subset of A, say A2, then all elements of A2 will cause TM(A) to halt in the accept state.

However, is it in general possible to then create a TM for A2, say TM(A2), such that A2 is the max possible set that halts TM(A2) in the accept state. Thus making A2 its language - and would this language be RE?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true that every subset of a recursively enumerable (RE) language is also RE. In fact, it make sense to say that a subset of a RE language is not RE more often than not.

For an example, let us consider the RE language, $\Sigma^*$ that contains all words. It is the language of the Turing machine which always halts and accepts in its first step. Note that every language is a subset of $\Sigma^*$. Every language that is not RE is an example.

---

Here are a few exercises for you to check.

Exercise 1. Is every subset of a regular language regular?

Exercise 2. Is every subset of a context-free language context-free?

Exercise 3. Is every subset of a recursive language recursive?

Comment: Ok great, thanks. That makes sense. The reason why I was asking was actually to understand why, for two RE langs A and B, why isn't A\B also RE, when A\B is a subset of A? Couldn't a TM be constructed to accept just A\B, since t.e. a TM that accepts A\B and more? But with what you're saying is it correct to say that for **some** RE langs A and B, A\B is RE, but this is not true in general? Thanks!

Comment: As you said, $A\setminus B$ may or may not be RE if both $A$ and $B$ are RE. For example, if $B$ is in fact recursive, then $A\setminus B$ is RE. For example, if $B$ is is not co-RE and $B\subset A$, then $A\setminus B$ is not RE.

Comment: Ok great, thank you! Really appreciate it.

Comment: The statement in my previous comment, "For example, if $B$ is is not co-RE and $B\subset A$, then $A\setminus B$ is not RE" should be corrected to "For example, if $B$ is not co-RE and $B\subset A$ and $A$ is recursive, then $A\setminus B$ is not RE".

Answer (score 3):

The trick to answering questions like this is to start by considering cases that make the question as simple as possible.  If you're lucky, the simplified question will be easy to answer and will give you the answer to the original question.

Here, you're asking "If a language is RE, are all its subsets?" One of the simplest RE languages we can try is $\Sigma^*$.  Not only is this a very simple language, but it also has many, many subsets. So, if any RE language was going to have non-RE subsets, it would have to be this one.  Considering this case turns the question into "Is every subset of $\Sigma^*$ RE?", which is just "Is every language RE?" and we see that the answer is no.

In other cases, it might be more beneficial to consider the empty language. (E.g., if you wanted to know whether every superset of an RE language is RE.)

Comment: Helps of course as you say to break it down into its most simple partitions.